# Why aren't these elements displaying inline-block?

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am trying to have it display an image (or other object) then prompt then the left image (or other object) all on one line (in a row). Why is it displaying each image on its own line?

```
var to_add = "<div>";
// add the left stimulus

if (trial.west_is_html) {
    to_add+="<img id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west' src="+trial.a_path_west.src +" height="+trial.a_path_west.height+" width="+trial.a_path_west.width+" style=display:'inline-block'>";
}

else {
      to_add+="<div id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-west'>"+trial.a_path_west+"</div>";
}

//show prompt if there is one
if (trial.prompt !== "") {
    to_add+="<div style=disaply'inline-block'>" + trial.prompt+ " </div>";
}

// show the right stimulus
if (trial.east_is_html) {
   to_add+="<img id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-east' src="+trial.a_path_east.src +" height="+trial.a_path_east.height+" width="+trial.a_path_east.width+" style=display:'inline-block'>";
}
else {
     to_add+="<div id='jspsych-single-stim-stimulus-east'>"+trial.a_path_east+"</div>";
}

to_add+="</div>"

display_element.append(to_add);
```

Thanks!

Comment: "disaply" is not same as "display". Typos hurt.

Answer (score 2):

you have typo:

```
style=display:'inline-block'
```

should be in all places:

```
style='display:inline-block'
```